# Buying a rack server for small business , please give me tips

Tags: small-business

Just to start the topic , I'm not really confident with that. My son is programmer and gave the tip to buy a server.
I'm running a small business and I want to buy a rack server instead of paying 30$ every month. I found one used server which I think it's good for me. I want to ask if that's enough to just run a website with 2-3 applications and a database environment? The server price is around 200$
Here are the server specs:

HP ProLiant DL160 G6 Rack

Processor (CPU): 2 x Intel Xeon L5630 2.13Hz Quad Core CPU
Memory (RAM): 16GB DDR3
Hard Disk Controller: On-board HP Smart Array B110i SATA RAID Controller (RAID 0, 1, 1+0)
Hard Disk Configuration: 4 x 3.5" SATA Hard Drive bays (No Caddies included)
Hard Disk Drive: None Installed
Graphics: 32MB shared supporting all display resolutions up to 1600x1200
Optical Drive: Not Installed
Network Ports: Embedded HP NC362i Integrated Dual Port Gigabit Server Adapter
Power: 460W Power Supply (PSU)

Expansion Slots: 1x PCI-Express x16 expansion slot
1x PCI-Express x8 Gen2 slot HL/LP (internal only)

Interface Ports: 1 x Serial
1 x Video
2 x Network RJ-45
USB 2.0 Ports 4 total: 2 rear, 2 front

Comment: That $30/month also pays for a datacenter, with redundant internet, power, security, etc. Not to mention bandwidth. Given that you're "not really confident" with servers, I'd suggest letting someone else manage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opinion:

The hosted solution will be much more reliable.  As ceejayoz said in his comment, they have much better equipment than you do and professionals to manage it.

You probably got a good deal on your server, but it is much older than what your hosted solution will run, and you'll spend a lot more time maintaining it.

Even if you were completely confident in your server maintenance skills, it sounds to me like your situation would still be better off with a hosted solution like you currently have.  Especially if your database is mission-critical, I'd stick with paying the pros to maintain it.  Hope that helps!

Note:  Your question is basically asking for opinions, which sometimes draws negative votes in StackExchange.  The community typically prefers more specific and objective question structure.  Just a tip :)